# Elasticsearch querying number of dates in array matching query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in the following form

```
PUT test_index/_doc/1
{
    "dates" : [
      "2018-07-15T14:12:12",
      "2018-09-15T14:12:12",
      "2018-11-15T14:12:12",
      "2019-01-15T14:12:12",
      "2019-03-15T14:12:12",
      "2019-04-15T14:12:12",
      "2019-05-15T14:12:12"],
    "message" : "hello world"
}
```

How do I query for documents such that there are `n` number of dates within the `dates` array falling in between two specified dates?

For example: Find all documents with 3 dates in the `dates` array falling in between `"2018-05-15T14:12:12"` and `"2018-12-15T14:12:12"` -- this should return the above document as `"2018-07-15T14:12:12"`, `"2018-09-15T14:12:12"` and `"2018-11-15T14:12:12"` fall between `"2018-05-15T14:12:12"` and `"2018-12-15T14:12:12"`.

Comment: For example, what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem. However came up with two solutions.

1) If you do not want to change your current mapping, you could query for the documents using query_string. Also note you will have to create the query object according to the range that you have. (**"\"2019-04-08\" OR \"2019-04-09\" OR \"2019-04-10\" "**)

```
      {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "dates",
      "query": "\"2019-04-08\" OR \"2019-04-09\" OR \"2019-04-10\" "
    }
  }
}
```

However,this type of a query only makes sense if the range is short.

2) So the second way is the nested method. But you will have to change your current mapping in such a way.

```
 {
  "properties": {
    "dates": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "YYYY-MM-dd"
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So your query will look something like this :-

```
     {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "dates",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "dates.key": {
                  "gte": "2018-04-01",
                  "lte": "2018-12-31"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: seems good, the Second solution is more efficient as compared to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dates as a [nested document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) and use [bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) aggregation.

```
{
  "empId":1,
  "dates":[
             { 
               "Days":"2019-01-01"
             },
             { 
               "Days":"2019-01-02"
             }
          ]
}
```

Mapping:

```
 "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
       "empId" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "dates" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "Days" : {
              "type" : "date"
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

```
GET profile/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "dates",
          "query": {
            "range": {
              "dates.Days": {
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "gte": "2019-05-01",
                "lte": "2019-05-30"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "terms_parent_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "empId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "availabilities": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dates"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avail": {
              "range": {
                "field": "dates.Days",
                "ranges": [
                  {
                    "from": "2019-05-01",
                    "to": "2019-05-30"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "aggs": {
                "count_Total": {
                  "value_count": {
                    "field": "dates.Days"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "max_hourly_inner": {
              "max_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "avail>count_Total"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "bucket_selector_page_id_term_count": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "children_count": "availabilities>max_hourly_inner"
            },
            "script": "params.children_count>=19;"  ---> give the number of days that should match
          }
        },
        "hits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10   
              }
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer to this, although I'm not sure how efficient it is compared to the other answers:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool" : {
        "filter" : {
          "script" : {
            "script" : {"source":"""
            int count = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<doc['dates'].length; ++i) {
              if (params.first_date < doc['dates'][i].toInstant().toEpochMilli() && doc['dates'][i].toInstant().toEpochMilli() < params.second_date) {
                count += 1; 
              }
            }
            if (count >= 2) {
              return true
            } else {
              return false
            }
            """,
            "lang":"painless",
            "params": {
              "first_date": 1554818400000,
              "second_date": 1583020800000
            }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

where the parameters are the two dates in epoch time. I've chosen 2 matches here, but obviously you can generalise to any number.

Comment: bucket selector approach will be faster than scripting

Comment: Yes, but the bucket selector approach requires the `dates` fields to be nested, which will be more expensive for indexing..